# Deforming UV mesh by dragging vertex

Tags: texturing, uv, transforms

I've recently gotten back into Blender and am currently unwrapping uvs for a model I'm developing. I remember vaguely of a feature that allows me to bend a uv mesh to expand or shrink areas by dragging a vertex in or out. An example where I find this useful is when I unwrap a head, and the face is microscopically in the middle compared to all the other features bordering the seams. I remember dragging areas on the face using the vertices to expand the face out and shrink the seam areas down so more detail can be shown on the actual face. Does anyone know how this is done or am I just mistaking this feature from another 3d program?

Comment: maybe you're talking about enabling the Proportional Editing option in the UV Editor?

Answer (score 1):

LIVE UNWRAP!
Thanks to moonboots comment, looking up proportional editing and uv map made me find the video that introduced the technique I was talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXyIhYcYmoo

Turns out I needed to have Live Unwrap checked and transform my pinned vertices on the EDGES of my unwrapped mesh.